# rails technoweenie / restful-authentication magi-code: Can't find `User#register!`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I recently installed the technoweenie / restful-authentication plugin (which works as promised), but while going through `users_controller#created`, I found a reference to a method call on the `user` model

```
 @user.register!
```

*Does anyone know where the method is defined?* I've pretty much search all of the generated code, and still don't see a register method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's defined in restful-authentication/lib/authorization/stateful_roles.rb

```
    event :register do
      transitions :from => :passive, :to => :pending, :guard => Proc.new {|u| !(u.crypted_password.blank? && u.password.blank?) }
    end
```

The actual method `register!` is created dynamically from this event by the acts_as_state_machine plugin that should be in your project as well. This method was inserted into your controller because when you generated your controller you specified either `--stateful` or '--aasm'.

There is a very good write up on acts_as_state_machine [here](http://rails.aizatto.com/2007/05/24/ruby-on-rails-finite-state-machine-plugin-acts_as_state_machine/) if you would like to learn more.

Comment: no problem, I actually was trying to figure out where this was coming from last week :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, was tearing my hair out over it

Answer (score 0):

Run the restful auth generators